Apply CSS rules if the previous element has a different attribute value
Is there any way to apply style if the previous element has a different attribute value with pure CSS?
Lets say I have a DOM like:
<div id="1" foo="1"></div>
<div id="2" foo="1"></div>
<div id="3" foo="2"></div>
<div id="4" foo="2"></div>
<div id="5" foo="3"></div>
<div id="6" foo="3"></div>
<div id="7" foo="3"></div>

I want to apply styles to element when its foo value differs from foo value of a previous element. In the example above, these are elements with IDs 3 and 5.

When u have different ids then u can target element by their ids.  Not clear what are the requirements.

What have you tried? I don't understand what you're trying to do since it would seem, as Naeem suggested, that targeting the elements by their IDs would suffice. Can you elaborate and explain the problem more clearly please?

@NaeemAkhtar I want to apply styles if value of foo attribute of two consecutive elements are different. ID added only as reference to a certain element.

You could use the next sibling combinator and the :not() pseudo class as below but you'd have to target a specific attribute value. I don't think it's possible to do it for any arbitrary change in attribute value without using javascript.


:not([foo="2"]) + [foo="2"] {
  background-color: red;
}

:not([foo="3"]) + [foo="3"] {
  background-color: blue;
}
<div id="1" foo="1">1</div>
<div id="2" foo="1">1</div>
<div id="3" foo="2">2</div>
<div id="4" foo="2">2</div>
<div id="5" foo="3">3</div>
<div id="6" foo="3">3</div>
<div id="7" foo="3">3</div>




Point is I dont know exact attribure value, ie it could be foo="xyz" and next one is foo="abc"

Definitely a job for Javascript then but I might be proven wrong!

Looks like it's not possible from this answer

Yearh, I think its answer my question, thx!
